# .NET LinkTagHelper - how can I use it for CSS CDN files without explicit css class selectors?

Tags: html, css, .net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .NET Core 2.1 app and in it I am pulling a few resources from CDN's via the "[LinkTagHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.linktaghelper?view=aspnetcore-2.1)" .NET helper.

I started with an obvious example (that works just fine) like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      asp-fallback-href="~/lib/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only"
      asp-fallback-test-property="position"
      asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
```

Now that's all good, Fallback works (if needed) CSS "sr-only" class is tested for presence and correctness.

I am also trying to do the same thing for this CSS file on their CDN:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-EkHEUZ6lErauT712zSr0DZ2uuCmi3DoQj6ecNdHQXpMpFNGAQ48WjfXCE5n20W+R"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      asp-fallback-href="~/lib/dist/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"
      asp-fallback-test-class=".dataTable"
      asp-fallback-test-property="clear"
      asp-fallback-test-value="both" />
```

Now in that example above, the test css class, property and value options in place are wrong - they do not work, so the fallback is always loaded. I wonder if it's because in the dataTables css file ([here  is the un-minified version](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css)), there is no "class only" selector specified, they are all type + class.

So, I suspect that I can't do what I want here because I can't choose an appropriate CSS selector to use in the LinkTagHelper! If it's always going to fall back, then I may as well not have the CDN.

Am I using LinkTagHelper wrong, or otherwise not thinking about this properly?

(I know I can just always load it from my site and not bother with these shennanigans, but... if I'm doing CDN for one library, may as well be consistent).

Answer (score 1):

> Now in that example above, the test css class, property and value
>   options in place are wrong - they do not work, so the fallback is
>   always loaded. I wonder if it's because in the dataTables css file
>   (here is the un-minified version), there is no "class only" selector
>   specified, they are all type + class.
>
> So, I suspect that I can't do what I want here because I can't choose
>   an appropriate CSS selector to use in the LinkTagHelper! If it's
>   always going to fall back, then I may as well not have the CDN.

I went ahead an took a look at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/LinkTagHelper.cs) to see what is actually happening when you use the helper.

If you follow along the source code, you will see the helper is basically adding

1. A `link` tag with original CSS file
2. A `meta` tag with class property set to value specified in **asp-fallback-test-class** attribute
3. Lastly, it adds a script which will verify if meta element's style value for **asp-fallback-test-property** is same as **asp-fallback-test-value** or not. If value is not same it adds another `link` to CSS file specified in **asp-fallback-href**.

For your case, the css file has all selectors in CSS with some tag (table.dataTable) so as per my understanding it will be hard to findout if CSS file was loaded or not and will always result in fallback CSS file.

You can follow along original feature request over [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1580).

> Am I using LinkTagHelper wrong, or otherwise not thinking about this properly?
>   As per my understanding you are not, it just that your case is an edge case, if you will.

Lastly, just a minor change `asp-fallback-test-class=".dataTable"` in your question should be `asp-fallback-test-class="dataTable"` (without **.**).